# LINQ query records based on date array

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a table (I am using Entity Model) and filtered that table using LINQ query which is working fine.
Now I want to filter the records on the basis of array of dates. I am not able to implement IN clause on array of dates

```
filteredList = leadsNewAndScheduled.Where(lead =>  
              (LeadTypeIDs.Contains(lead.TYPE_ID.ToString()) ||
              LeadTypeIDs == string.Empty) &&
              (priorityIDs.Contains(lead.PRIORITY_ID.ToString()) ||
              priorityIDs == string.Empty) &&
              (((lead.EXPIRED_ON <= dateExpiry ||
              Convert.ToDateTime(lead.EXPIRED_ON) == DateTime.Today.Date) &&
              lead.STATUS_ID == (int)Enumerations.LeadStatus.New) ||
              lead.STATUS_ID == (int)Enumerations.LeadStatus.Active) &&
              (lead.START_TIME IN (arrAppointmentDates))
            ).ToList();
```

I want your help in following

```
(lead.START_TIME IN (arrAppointmentDates))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem while declaring list of dates and then applying contains clause in LINQ query.

example:

```
//list of dates.
List<DateTime> arrAppointmentDates;

//change in query
arrAppointmentDates.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(lead.START_TIME).Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Write your query without the date condition like

```
var query = leadsNewAndScheduled.Where(lead =>  
              (LeadTypeIDs.Contains(lead.TYPE_ID.ToString()) ||
              LeadTypeIDs == string.Empty) && ....
```

Then write

```
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Lead>();

  foreach (DateTime date in dates)
  {
    DateTime temp = date;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.START_TIME == temp);
  }

  var result = query.Where(predicate).ToList(); // Don't call ToList() earlier
```

However please note that if you're using Entity Framework you need to call AsExpandable() on the entity set before applying predicates on it like so:

```
return objectContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks hasan, 
I created a class PredicateBuilder from your given source and implemented following code; 

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<LeadGetNewAndScheduledByEmployee_type>();

foreach (DateTime date in arrAppointmentDates)
{
    DateTime temp = date;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.START_TIME).Date == temp);
}

filteredList = filteredList.Where(predicate).ToList();

But it gives me following error

'System.Collections.Generic.List<EntityModel.LeadGetNewAndScheduledByEmployee_type>' does not contain a definition for 'Where'.

Any help in this ...

Comment: Do you have System.Linq namespace included?

Comment: Yes I have Included System.Linq

Comment: What is the type of leadsNewAndScheduled and where it is coming from?

Comment: leadsNewAndScheduled is of complex type Of Entity Model (i.e. List<LeadGetNewAndScheduledByEmployee_type>()) which is an output from a MSSQL Stored Procedure.